# Itertool Combinations Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Somehow I could not finding the proper solution for my problem. I wanted to calculate the sum between the Unit and Scen column with equal values for the same fact_date. The output should look like the following:

**Output:**

```
Combination Unit_Com    Scen    Value_Sum   Town    Country
11-Apr      a,b         1       28          Town A  USA
11-Apr      a,b         2       31          Town A  USA
11-Apr      a,c         1       30          Town A  USA
11-Apr      a,c         2       30          Town A  USA
11-Apr      a,d         1       31          Town A  USA
11-Apr      a,d         2       29          Town A  USA
11-Apr      b,c         1       32          Town A  USA
11-Apr      b,c         2       39          Town A  USA
11-Apr      b,d         1       33          Town A  USA
11-Apr      b,d         2       38          Town A  USA
11-Apr      c,d         1       35          Town A  USA
11-Apr      c,d         2       37          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,b         1       28          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,b         2       25          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,c         1       32          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,c         2       26          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,d         1       38          Town A  USA
10-Apr      a,d         2       22          Town A  USA
10-Apr      b,c         1       24          Town A  USA
10-Apr      b,c         2       27          Town A  USA
10-Apr      b,d         1       30          Town A  USA
10-Apr      b,d         2       23          Town A  USA
10-Apr      c,d         1       34          Town A  USA
10-Apr      c,d         2       24          Town A  USA
```

which is calulated the in the following way:

```
fact_date: 11-Apr
Town: Town A
Country: USA

Unit: a
Scen(Unit a): 1
Value: 13

Unit: b
Scen(Unit a): 1
Value: 15

**Output (as shown above):**
fact_date: 11-Apr
Unit_Combo: a,b
Scen: 1
Value_Sum: 28
Town: Town A
Country USA
```

This should be then performed for every fact_date.

And at the end the combinations between **`Town A and Town B`** and there also, e.g. a,e etc.

Unfortunatly I dont receive any combination and I am stuck here:

**UPDATE:**

I updated the code but somehow still receiving the wrong output

```
calculating date: 11-Apr
11-Apr 1,1 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 28
11-Apr 1,2 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 33
11-Apr 1,1 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 30
11-Apr 1,2 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 32
11-Apr 1,1 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 31
11-Apr 1,2 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 31
11-Apr 1,1 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 23
11-Apr 1,2 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 26
11-Apr 1,1 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 27
11-Apr 1,2 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 27
11-Apr 1,1 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 33
11-Apr 1,2 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 23
calculating date: 10-Apr
10-Apr 2,1 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 26
10-Apr 2,2 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 31
10-Apr 2,1 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 28
10-Apr 2,2 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 30
10-Apr 2,1 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 29
10-Apr 2,2 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 29
10-Apr 2,1 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 21
10-Apr 2,2 a,b Town A,Town A USA,USA 24
10-Apr 2,1 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 25
10-Apr 2,2 a,c Town A,Town A USA,USA 25
10-Apr 2,1 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 31
10-Apr 2,2 a,d Town A,Town A USA,USA 21
```

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'fact_date': ['11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','11-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr','10-Apr'],
                   'Unit': ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f','g','g','h','h','i','i','j','j','k','k','l','l'],
                   'Town': ['Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town A','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B','Town B'],
                   'Scen': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
                   'Value': [13,11,15,20,17,19,18,18,18,12,10,13,14,14,20,10,18,17,15,19,11,14,14,17,19,10,16,10,16,19,12,11],
                   'Country': ['USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA']})


test_df = pd.DataFrame([])

cluster_names = df['fact_date'].unique()
disjoint_clusters = []
for idx,item in enumerate(cluster_names):
    df[df['fact_date'] == item]

    print('calculating date: ' +str(item))

    for j in range(idx+1, len(df)):
        if df.iloc[idx]['Unit'] != df.iloc[j]['Unit'] and df.iloc[idx]['Town'] == 'Town A' and df.iloc[j]['Town'] == 'Town A':

            print(item,
                  str(df.iloc[idx]['Scen'])+str(',')+str(df.iloc[j]['Scen']), 
                  df.iloc[idx]['Unit']+str(',')+df.iloc[j]['Unit'],
                  df.iloc[idx]['Town']+str(',')+df.iloc[j]['Town'],
                  df.iloc[idx]['Country']+str(',')+df.iloc[j]['Country'],
                  df.iloc[idx]['Value']+df.iloc[j]['Value'])
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the sentence about `Town A` and `Town B`. Do you want the combinations unit a,e or not? if yes what should be the town then?

Comment: @Ben.T, thanksa for the answer. yes I want them as additional output but first the ones I showed above. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this way will give you the expected output of your question. The idea is to use `groupby` on the columns `'fact_date','Country','Town','Scen'` and then use `combinations` from `itertools`on the grouped dataframe for the values in columns `'Value','Unit'`. You can use a list comprehension and `pd.DataFrame` to create directly the result dataframe:

```
from itertools import combinations
df_res = pd.DataFrame([list(name_g) + [val1+val2,'{},{}'.format(unit1,unit2)] 
                       for name_g, df_g in df.groupby(['fact_date','Country','Town','Scen']) 
                       for ((val1, unit1), (val2, unit2)) in combinations(df_g[['Value','Unit']].values,2)],
                      columns=['Combination','Country','Town','Scen','Value_Sum','Unit_Com'])
```

you may need to reorder the columns and to get the same range of output, then you can do:

```
print (df_res[df_res['Town'] == 'Town A'])
   Combination Country    Town  Scen  Value_Sum Unit_Com
0       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         28      a,b
1       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         32      a,c
2       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         38      a,d
3       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         24      b,c
4       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         30      b,d
5       10-Apr     USA  Town A     1         34      c,d
6       10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         25      a,b
7       10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         26      a,c
8       10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         22      a,d
9       10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         27      b,c
10      10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         23      b,d
11      10-Apr     USA  Town A     2         24      c,d
24      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         28      a,b
25      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         30      a,c
26      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         31      a,d
27      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         32      b,c
28      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         33      b,d
29      11-Apr     USA  Town A     1         35      c,d
30      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         31      a,b
31      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         30      a,c
32      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         29      a,d
33      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         39      b,c
34      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         38      b,d
35      11-Apr     USA  Town A     2         37      c,d
```

EDIT: for doing the same thing with `Town`, you can do it like:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame([list(name_g) + [val1+val2,'{},{}'.format(unit1,unit2), '{},{}'.format(town1,town2)] 
                       for name_g, df_g in df.groupby(['fact_date','Country','Scen']) 
                       for ((val1, unit1, town1), (val2, unit2, town2)) in combinations(df_g[['Value','Unit','Town']].values,2)],
                      columns=['Combination','Country','Scen','Value_Sum','Unit_Com','Town'])
```

See the difference is that the column `Town` is not in the `groupby` anymore but in the columns selected in the `combinations` and the small changes to make it work properly.

For selecting these combinations randomly, I would suggest to have a look at the function [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and for example, if you want 10 of them, you can do:

```
print (df_res.sample(n=10))
    Combination Country  Scen  Value_Sum Unit_Com           Town
7        10-Apr     USA     1         24      b,c  Town A,Town A
66       11-Apr     USA     1         30      b,f  Town A,Town B
31       10-Apr     USA     2         22      a,i  Town A,Town B
18       10-Apr     USA     1         39      d,i  Town A,Town B
72       11-Apr     USA     1         28      c,g  Town A,Town B
109      11-Apr     USA     2         33      f,g  Town B,Town B
41       10-Apr     USA     2         24      c,d  Town A,Town A
99       11-Apr     USA     2         38      c,f  Town A,Town B
84       11-Apr     USA     2         31      a,b  Town A,Town A
88       11-Apr     USA     2         30      a,f  Town A,Town B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. I still have some more questions. How would i cahnge the code making the same combinations but with Town A and Town B in the same way? And Is there a possibility selecting these combinations randomized? Thanks.

Comment: @NewNY1990 see my EDIT if I understood your comment correctly, it should do the job

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I was looking for. I still have a question concerning choosing the combinations randomly. Maybe I was not clear enough. Instead doing the combinations based on a nested loop, I would choose randomly these combinations. Is it clearer?

Comment: @NewNY1990 Not sure I understand :( do you mean you want only the combinations with Unit being a and b for example?

Comment: What I mean is that currently I am doing the combinations based on a kind of "nested loop way" and combining two lists in a order. Now I want to do these combinations randomly. I will get definatly several time equal combinations but this is fine. Is it clearer? Furthermore, Is it possible to multiply in each of the examples above the first value with -1 when creating the pairs, e.g.:   `fact_date: 11-Apr
Town: Town A
Country: USA

Unit: a
Scen(Unit a): 1
Value: 13*(-1)

Unit: b
Scen(Unit a): 1
Value: 15

Unit_Combo: a,b
Scen: 1
Value_Sum: 2
Town: Town A
Country USA`

Comment: @NewNY1990 One way would be to create `df_res2` the same way but changing this part: `pd.Da ... + [-val1+val2, ...` add a minus before `val1`. Not sure it's what you want and then you can concatenate them together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Doing that results to a wrong figure. Instead eg Scen 1 a is the value 13 and for Scen 1 b is 15 I should get 2 and not - 8. Just to say it simple I want to subtract instead to add.

Comment: @NewNY1990 sorry, less on the site for a while and I forgot to give a try. I think you don't look at the right date, I indeed get -8 for a and b Scen 1 but for April 10, where val for a is 18 and for b is 10, so good figure. When using this method, it seems that `df_res` is sort by date (not sure why like this). I understand why it's confusing though, the sum is the same for both date :)

Comment: sorry somehow did not received a message that you replied. Yes you were right. I just looked into the wrong line. It works. Thanks! The only open question is still for me, as currently I only build the combination based on two lists. How can I build randomly e.g. 500 combinations using rand (which means there can be also doubled trippeled etc combinations which are euqlly somehting like np.random.choice(500, combination, replace=False).)?

Comment: @NewNY1990 Hi, sorry for not answering before, your comment does not really make sense to me. I think you should ask a new question with more detailed expected output. You can link this one to explain the background. Especially because, while related, it's not your original question

Comment: I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194303/itertools-2000-randomized-combinations-python-dataframe